# Android: 50dip is different size on different devices?

Tags: android

My understanding of the density independent pixel, is that it will render as the same size regardless of the screen dpi and dimensions.  I created an image button of with and height of 50dip.  On my medium dpi Samsung Galaxy Tab, this button measures about 10mm x 10mm (measured with a ruler.  On my large, hdpi Acer Iconia Tab, the button measures about 7mm x 7mm.  I would have expected the two buttons to have the same actual size.  Am I doing something wrong, or is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both previous answers are correct. The problem lies in that not only changes the size in inces, but also the number of total pixels.

For a solution, you will need to create different xml layout files in `res/layout-normal` and `res/layout-large`, to adjust for screen resolution changes. Still, given that these folders group ranges of devices, you will have some variation in size.

Alternatively, if you strictly need a specific fixed size for a View, set up its width and height as `"10mm"`

---

```
public static final int layout_width               Since: API Level 1
```

> Specifies the basic width of the view. This is a required attribute for any view inside of a containing layout manager. Its value may be a dimension (such as "12dip") for a constant width or one of the special constants.
>
> May be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), **in (inches), mm (millimeters).**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_width

---

For a list of screen sizes, resolutions and dpi values, take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density

To calculate the real dpi value, check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#Calculation_of_monitor_PPI

Comment: I continue to be confused.  If my IconiaTab is 160 dpi, then 50dip = 50 pixel = 50/160 inches = 5/16th of an inch.  And if my samsung tab is 240dpi, then 50 dip = 75 pixel = 75/240 inches = 5/16th of an inch.  So, the 2 image buttons should measure the same size?

Comment: @ab11 Assuming the galaxy tab is the 7 inch one, it is 170 dpi, not 240

Answer (score 2):

You've got it the wrong way round, the Galaxy Tab is `HDPI` and the Acer Tab is `MDPI`.
50dips is 50 pixels on an `MDPI` device or 75 pixels on an `HDPI` device, which should translate to roughly the same physical size.

However things are slightly different due to the much larger screen size on 3.0 tablets. In these cases often using the `HDPI` assets gives a better size.

Comment: So, if I would like to ensure that my button is always about the size of a fingertip (the size of 50dip button on my Galaxy Tab is about right), what is the best strategy?

Comment: For Honeycomb, I would use different sizes than other versions (you can have res/values-11/ folder and place Honeycomb specific dimensions and things in here). And I would use HDPI sized graphics even though the screen is MDPI - so make your button 75dips when run on Honeycomb, 50 dips on prior versions.

Comment: I continue to be confused. If my IconiaTab is 160 dpi, then 50dip = 50 pixel = 50/160 inches = 5/16th of an inch. And if my samsung tab is 240dpi, then 50 dip = 75 pixel = 75/240 inches = 5/16th of an inch. So, the 2 image buttons should measure the same size?

Comment: Yes but they are not exactly those DPIs - in fact the Galaxy Tab is actually 170dpi even though it identifies itself as an `HDPI` device - just because it looked better this way. Similarly I would not be surprised if the DPI of the Iconica was not 160.

Comment: Well, that is surprising.  If I wanted my buttons to always be 8mm x 8mm, would it be safe/smart to set there dimensions to layout_width    ="8mm", layout_height ="8mm"?

Comment: Yes that should give you the same physical size across devices.

Comment: Inexplicably, they don't.  If I set width and height to "10mm".  The button measures 10x10 on my IconiaTab, but 8x8 on my Galaxy!

Answer (score 0):

from: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html (emphasis added)

Density-independent pixel (dp)
A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
**The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen**, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use. **The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels**. You should always use dp units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different densities.