# Which different resources for densitys and sizes should I make?

Tags: android, resources, screen, dpi

I've been reading the Android documentation, and they mention support for different screen densities, as well as different screen sizes.

If I'm not mistaken, these are the design DPI values I should be using:
LDPI=120
MDPI=160
HDPI=240
XHDPI=300

I can also see that in Eclipse, I have drawable folders for each of these.

However my question is regarding screen size, because I don't see a place where I should place resources depending on screen size.

For example, my AOC Breeze is 120DPI, but as a XLARGE screen (8 inches). I imagine there are smaller devices with a NORMAL screen (4 inches) but MDPI or HDPI screens. Where should resources for similar device go?

Is there a place for resources of different DPI/screen size combinations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to create different layouts for different screen sizes, e.g. `layout-normal` and `layout-large`

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917875/android-resources-folders-by-screen-size/5918048#5918048) for a more detail explanation, and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965645/android-50dip-is-different-size-on-different-devices/5965904#5965904) for links to a table with different resolutions.